# Relation between the Schwarz and Test function spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Consider the map $\varphi_a: B(0,a) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined as:
\begin{align*}
\varphi_a(x) = \frac{x}{a^2-|x|^2}
\end{align*}
where $|.|$ denotes the $l_2$ norm. Now if we take a Schwarz function $s \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ we can define a new map $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:
\begin{align*}
\Phi = s\circ\varphi_a 
\end{align*}
in $B(0,a)$, and extended to $0$ outside. My guess is that the object I am getting is a $C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function. Is this true in general?(it works for maps like $e^{-x^2}$) Also, can every $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ function be factored in this way?

Comment: You have defined $\Phi$ only on $B(0,a)$. How can it be in $C_c^{\infty} (\mathbb R^{n})$

Comment: Extended to 0 outside...